# How to create a software-implemented drive

Tags: winapi, filesystems

There are some applications (let us call them providers), which (when running) provide a virtual file and directory structure under a new drive letter. Access requests from other processes to those files and directories are served by the provider.
One example of such provider could be the Google Drive for Windows (the new one, not the old Backup and Sync), which maps the contents of your Google Drive to a chosen drive letter.

I thought there should be some simple user-mode API, which should allow my app to provide a new drive and the contents of files and directories on it. I thought that many applications use such API, but I cannot find it. The closest I could get are IFS (installable file system drivers) and file system filter drivers, but those are kernel-mode and they seem too complex. They just seem not designed to accomplish such task.

So, what API should I use to make a simple software-implemented drive?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-createvirtualdisk

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9466f70b-d0b6-499a-b9de-fd8b3aeb8db0/

Comment: With Google Drive aren't the files actually there? There's a service behind the scenes that does the sync for you?

Comment: @David Heffernan: This was the case with the old Google Drive client called Backup and Sync. The new client creates a virtual drive.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. In the Google Drive case, it uses Dokan: https://dokan-dev.github.io/ (requires a kernel driver). In OneDrive case, it uses the Cloud API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine in the case of Box Drive, it uses another kernel driver (commercial) https://www.callback.com/cbfsconnect/ but you can also use a Shell Namespace Extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works which doesn't require a kernel driver

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions in the comments there is also now the [Projected Filesystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_projfs/), which allows software to provide a drive-like interface though callbacks and not just by creating an actual disk image. It is my understanding that Projected FS is how, for instance, SQL Server does its table-backed files interface.